# Get error while execute remote stored procedure sql server

Tags: sql-server, exec, credentials, linked-server

Why i get error: Login failed for user 'BLALBA'?

I have linked server from sqlserver1 to sqlserver2, and i can do

***select 
from sqlserver2.database.dbo.Table***

and able to see tree calatog.

But still have problem with execution stored procedure, like this: **EXEC sqlserver2.master.dbo.Send**
On **sqlserver2** have login **BLALBA** with sysadmin role.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
EXEC (@sql) AT <linkedserver>
```